# C# CS0019 IntPtr

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors, intptr

I encountered a snippet of C# source code as following

```
int* ptr = ...;
int  w = ...;

int* ptr3 = ptr + (IntPtr)w;

CS0019: Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int*' and 'System.IntPtr'
```

I guess this code was trying to move the ptr address forward by w which is dependent on the OS. Is this correct and how can I make this code compile?

Comment: Side note: if you don't know what code is supposed to do maybe you should not be writing it yet... Do you really need to use unsafe code and pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not correct syntax.  It is very unclear what you are trying to accomplish so just guessing here.  If you want to move the pointer forward by "w" ints then use:

```
  int* ptr3 = ptr + w;
```

Which adds 4*w to the pointer value since an int is 4 bytes.  This is equivalent to treating ptr3 as a pointer into an array of ints where w is the array element offset.  And the way the C language treats pointers.

If you meant to increment the address by w then avoid using IntPtr, the C# language forbids using the + operator on an IntPtr, even though that's permitted by the CLR.  You'll need to do some casting instead:

```
  int* ptr3 = (int*)((byte*)ptr + w);
```

Comment: I was trying to increment the pointer address by w. Since int type is 4 bytes on x86 and 8 bytes on 64bit OS, I just wanted to make sure the code works on either machine.

Comment: An int is 4 bytes on any architecture.

Answer (score 3):

if you want to use pointers you have to wrap the code in unsafe { } and flip the allow unsafe switch in project properties

[image]

```
unsafe 
{
  //pointer code here
}
```

Comment: Not having this option turned on generates an entirely different error message.